# Can't scroll to the bottom of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I'm working on simple chat app. When user open chat activity he has to see the messages scrolled to the bottom. But now it doesn't scroll to the bottom. It scrolls to the middle of the last message. See screenshot:
[image]

The second problem is - when I click in EditText field to type new message, the keyboard is hiding my messages. I expected to pull up the EditText field with Messages but it just pull up EditText without Messages. Se the screen shot:
[image]

How to scroll to very bottom of RecyclerView and how to pull up edit text with messages?

My code look like this:

```
messagesRecycler = findViewById(R.id.messagesRecycler);
messagesRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
layoutManagerMess = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
layoutManagerMess.scrollToPosition(messages.size() - 1);
adapterMessages = new AdapterMessages(messages, this, avatar);
messagesRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerMess);
messagesRecycler.setAdapter(adapterMessages);
```

Comment: Show us your layout xml files for your fragment and your recyclerview item.

Comment: Have you tried         layoutManager.stackFromEnd = true .

Comment: @MiniChip yes I tried. It works. But if I use `layoutManagerMess.setStackFromEnd(true);`then if only one message in list it will shown in the bottom. I need it in the top

Comment: so how do you solve it at the end?